# Change Mozilla readonly attribute

Tags: selenium, firefox, firefox-addon, geckodriver

Is it possible to change Mozilla's readonly attributes:
Specifically changing:

```
navigator.webdriver = false;
//changing it from true to false;
```

I know changing the *dom.webdriver.enabled* value in the about config removes the navigator.webdriver variable, however I would like for the following outcome to be true

```
navigator.webdriver === false;
//should return true
```

It's worth mentioning that by default the value is always **false**, but when running Firefox with Selenium the value changes to **true**
I am open for any methods, since I have full control of both the browser:Mozilla and the browser profile. *Hopefully I won't need to recompile Firefox*.

Comment: re-build selenium

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg would you know what look for, in terms of where the code I need to change is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `Object.defineProperty(navigator, "webdriver", {value: false})` in the page's context.